# C++ Win32 -- COM Method: equivalent C declaration

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I've been told that every COM method callable from C++ code (take for instance `IHTMLDocument2::write`) has an equivalent C declaration, usable from C code...

How do I find it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular interface is documented as being provided by `<mshtml.h>`. Now, as it happens the second and third line of that file are:

```
// Include the full header file that works for C
#include "mshtmlc.h"
```

Looking into that file, we find the declaration

```
    /* [id][vararg] */ HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE *write )( 
        IHTMLDocument2 * This,
        /* [in] */ __RPC__in SAFEARRAY * psarray);
```

Note that this is actually a **pointer** to the `IHTMLDocument2::write` method.

Sometimes the C declaration is the same header; sometimes the declaration isn't publicly available. But the COM standard is an ABI (a *binary* interface) designed such that you can always write a C declaration. Could be painful though.

Comment: Looks painful indeed ;-)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Method calls of the type `R Interface::Foo(T1, ..., Tn)` simply translate to `R Foo(Interface*, T1, ..., Tn)`.

They are available when compiling as C, i.e. `__cplusplus` not defined, or `CINTERFACE` is defined.